# Resetting json file with button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a todo list program and I want it to be reset to a predefined set of json within the json file once a button is clicked. For example, if the json file was full with data and someone clicked the button I want it to edit the json file to just say:

```
[{"completed":false,"task":"Kitchen - Sweep Floor","important":false}]
```

This is on cpanel latest using the latest stable php version. I've tried fwrite and file_put_contents but can't seem to get it working.

This is what I've tried already:

```
<html>
<h2>Click</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
    <button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
echo file_put_contents("test.json","[{"completed":false,"task":"Kitchen - Sweep Floor","important":false}]");
}
?>
</html>
```

When clicking the button nothing happens, no errors or anything?

Comment: nothing happens because `action=""`

Comment: Consider JavaScript if you don't need to persist the data. `<button name="click" onclick="reset();">Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">function reset() { jsonFile = ''; }</script>`. If you want to do it right, consider using AJAX GET/POST: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: action = "" is ok. the script will post to the current url

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned an action to the form, for this to work you should add the URL of the current page (so it redirects to itsself). Only then the post request is sent.

PHP won't run anything asynchronous: stuff only happens on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your script - you have to escape the quotes in the string. Always look at the webserver error log or enable error display during development.
Here is the fixed code:

```
echo file_put_contents("test.json","[{\"completed\":false,\"task\":\"Kitchen - Sweep Floor\",\"important\":false}]");
```

You should use something like json_decode. Don't build json by hand:

```
$data = array(
"completed"=>false,
"task"=>"Kitchen - Sweep Floor",
"important"=>false
);
echo file_put_contents("test.json",json_encode($data));
```